# mySQL subquery slower than 2 separate queries

Tags: mysql, sql, select, subquery, query-optimization

I am breaking my head over a simple sub query. I have the following query witch runs for 30+ seconds:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING( 6pp, 1, 4 ) AS postcode
FROM 6pp
WHERE gemeenteID
IN (
    SELECT gebiedID
    FROM tmp_orderimport
    WHERE typeGebied = 'Gemeente'
    AND idorder =1733
    AND STATUS = TRUE );
```

Explain: 
[image: Explain]

If I break the query in 2 queries and first run the IN part, the whole thing takes no more than a second. But of course I prefer to use one query. The tables are in MYISAM. Any suggestions?

## Update:

Following Gordon Linoff's example. I changed the SQL to:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING( 6pp, 1, 4 ) AS postcode
FROM `6pp`
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
          FROM tmp_orderimport oi
          WHERE oi.gebiedID = `6pp`.gemeenteID AND
                typeGebied = 'Gemeente' AND idorder = 1733 AND STATUS = TRUE
         );
```

And added an index on tmp_orderimport(gebiedID, typeGebied, idorder, status). Now the query runs under 4 seconds.

New explain: 
[image: New SQL explain]

Comment: MySQL is **really** bad with sub-queries. Try to rewrite the statement as a join (that should be possible as you are using a `distinct` anyway).

Comment: Can you edit your question with the querys that take no mare than a second?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `exists` instead:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING( 6pp, 1, 4 ) AS postcode
FROM `6pp`
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM tmp_orderimport oi
              WHERE oi.gebiedID = `6pp`.gemeenteID AND
                    typeGebied = 'Gemeente' AND idorder = 1733 AND STATUS = TRUE
             );
```

You can also speed this up with an index on `tmp_orderimport(gebiedID, typeGebied, idorder, status)`.

MySQL can be inefficient (sometimes and depending on the version) when using `IN` with a subquery.  `EXISTS` usually fixes the problem.  The specific problem is that the subquery is run for each comparison.  When you create a temporary table, you circumvent that.

Comment: I tried this solution. But its still extremely long (currently 1m+). I have indexes on all the required fields. Is there a difference in making indexes on all fields individual or making one index with all fields in it?

Comment: @DennisvanSchaik . . . Yes, there is a big difference.  Although if you have an index on `tmp_orderimport(gebiedID)`, the query should work pretty probably well, depending on the selectivity of the rest of the `where` clause.

Comment: What does EXPLAIN say about this query?

Comment: EXISTS in combination with an index on tmp_orderimport(gebiedID, typeGebied, idorder, status) seems to do the trick. The query now takes aboud 4 seconds witch I think is acceptable. I will update my question with the new explain. 

Still I am curious how mysql treats separate indexes differently from one index with multiple fields. can you explain this?

Comment: @DennisvanSchaik . . . MySQL documentation actually does a pretty good job of describing how composite indexes work:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-column-indexes.html.

Answer (score 1):

Use **INNER JOIN** instead of **IN operator**

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING(a.6pp, 1, 4) AS postcode
FROM 6pp a
INNER JOIN tmp_orderimport b ON a.gemeenteID = b.gebiedID 
WHERE b.typeGebied = 'Gemeente' AND b.idorder =1733 AND b.STATUS = TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably MySQL is running the sub-query once for each record of the main query. This ends up causing an exponential processing.

His sub-query is independent of the main query, you could run first the sub-query and store the value in memory (maybe an temporary table), and then use the main query.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see anyone comment about your 6pp table and having an index on that for (gemeenteID, 6pp).  I would also have an index on your tmp_orderimport table on (idorder, tpeGebied, status, gebiedID) and then swap it around a bit.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
      SUBSTRING( P.6pp, 1, 4 ) AS postcode
   FROM 
      ( SELECT gebiedID
          FROM tmp_orderimport
         WHERE typeGebied = 'Gemeente'
           AND idorder =1733
           AND STATUS = TRUE ) G
      JOIN 6pp P
         on G.gebiedID = P.gemeenteID
```